# Global variable that count number of errors

Tags: ansible

Im new in Ansible. Im using playbooks/roles in Openstack and im searching for a Global variable or similar that count the number of errors in the playbook or at least that an error ocurred in some moment.
This is why (let say that this variable is called GLOB):

```
In Task:

---
# tasks file 

 - name: testing block
  block: 
  # List of tests to run in this test suite:
 
 - include: ../tests/DoThings.yml #API calls, http 50x possible errors: YES

  always: #Final task always executed
  - include: ../tests/Clear.yml #API calls, http 50x possible errors: YES
  - include: ../tests/Report.yml #NOT API calls, http 50x possible errors: NO, just log checker.
```

So if some error ocurred in  DoThings.yml i want to clear all the thing with Clear.yml and AFTER execute Report.yml, inside this i will check if GLOBAL var has 1 failed (one or more failed). This is because a failed can be

1. A "50x HTTP", that is impossible to predict, you have to try again (this is important to detect for me and differentiate from other errors)
2. A normal error for code mistake or similar, easy to fix (not important in this case)

Comment: I understand your question that you are looking for the [playbook summary of task exectuion](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#playbook-execution) which "_provides a summary of the nodes that were targeted and how they performed. General failures and fatal “unreachable” communication attempts are kept separate in the counts_" at the bottom.

Comment: Hi @U880D , Im trying to discard 50x HTTP error's from Openstack commands (When you use Openstack, you have HTTP request to the API, sometimes the response are 50x, like 502, 500, and you have to send the command again) because this kind of error are not predictable (not a human fail also ). So i think to check some Global Flag that i can check after i do Clean.yml (that also can fail) in Report.yml